# When I add a certain line to my Javascript code it removes the onclick function I have for my HTML function.

Tags: javascript, html, function, cookies, browser

I am coding a game and I need to save some variables with cookies. I added a line that should execute a Javascript function that will check if the user has already been on the website and made an account or not, and if they have not it will ask for a username. However, when I added the line that should run the function, the function after it failed, and so did it.
This is a portion of my code:

```
<script>
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
function checkCookie() {
    var username=getCookie("username");
    if (username!="") {
        alert("Welcome again " + username);
    } else {
        username = prompt("Please enter your username:", "");
        if (username != "" && username != null) {
            setCookie("username", username, 365);
        }
    }
}
</script>

<button id="open_market">Market</button>
<script>
checkCookie();
open_market.onclick = function() {
  window.open("https://thenumnut.github.io/Wars-of-Shares/Market");
}
</script>
```

The line that I added to run the function was "checkCookie();". After I added that line the button with id "open_market" would not respond when clicked. This makes me think that the code failed/crashed on the line before it when I said "checkCookie();". 
If anybody can find the problem with this code I will greatly appreciate it. You can see in the code the github link to my code on github if you would like to see my full code.

Comment: Well, first problem for testing is that the function you're using, getCookie(), isn't defined in the code you provided.

Comment: And it works just fine when I tested it now - I added the getCookie() function from your github-page, and it opens the correct page when I click the button "Market". So the problem is not in the code you posted here, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added your getCookie() function, and apart from that, just added a bit of HTML around the tags, and here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <script> function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return ""; }

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/"; } function checkCookie() {
    var username=getCookie("username");
    if (username!="") {
        alert("Welcome again " + username);
    } else {
        username = prompt("Please enter your username:", "");
        if (username != "" && username != null) {
            setCookie("username", username, 365);
        }
    } } </script> </head> <body> <button id="open_market">Market</button> <script> checkCookie(); open_market.onclick = function() {   window.open("https://thenumnut.github.io/Wars-of-Shares/Market"); } </script> </body> </html>
```

It seems to be working fine

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly now. I was copying and pasting quite a bit so I must of got muddled with what I had and what I hadn't added.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript this is often a sign, that there is a bug in `checkCookie();`. I don't see one at first glance, but your browser should show you the bug in his console.

You can open the console in most browsers (e.g. Firefox, IE) by rightclicking somewhere on your page and then choose "Inspect Element". Now change to the tab Console.

If you don't understand the error message, just post it here

Comment: I was running it through Github. This means that it does not show any error message. Also, I am using Safari on mobile, therefore I cannot Inspect Element.

Comment: Github does not prevent the developer tools in a browser from working. Safari on mobile [doesn't prevent you from using developer tools](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/remote-debugging-ios-safari-on-os-x-windows-and-linux/). Even if it did, the wouldn't prevent you from testing the problem in another browser.

Answer (score 0):

Open your browser's developer tools. **Read the error message**

`checkCookie();` calls a function which has `var username=getCookie("username");`.

You haven't defined a `getCookie` function, so it throws an exception and stops execution.